# Rename jpg files in thousands of folders to avatar.jpg and main.jpg

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have thousands of folders with 2 jpg files in them..

For example the folder 1052 has:

```
4a4df84f7e8d78100ceed89b368be78d.jpg
thumb_4a4df84f7e8d78100ceed89b368be78d.jpg
```

I want to rename the one that begins with `thumb_` to `avatar.jpg` and the other one to `main.jpg`

How to do this? Will cmd rename commands help or will I need to write a windows batch script ? If so what the the commands to be used ?

I use Windows.

Comment: You need to write a windows batch script...

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out a trick.

Rename everything with thumb to xyz extension

```
for /R %x in (thumb*.jpg) do ren "%x" avatar.xyz
```

Rename remaining job file to main.jpg:

```
for /R %x in (*.jpg) do ren "%x" main.jpg
```

Rename xyz back to jpg

```
for /R %x in (*.xyz) do ren "%x" *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do all in one shot:

```cmd
rem // Iterate all `*.jpg` files:
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /S /B /A:-D *.jpg') do (
    rem /* Extract the part of the file name before the first `_`; the leading `-` is added
    rem    to avoid files like `__thumb___xxx.jpg` to be renamed to `avatar.jpg`: */
    for /F "delims=_ eol=_" %%I in ("-%%~nF") do (
        rem // Check the extracted file name part and rename the file accordingly:
        if /I "%%I"=="-thumb" (
            ren "%%~F" "avatar.*"
        ) else (
            ren "%%~F" "main.*"
        )
    )
)
```

To try this directly in command prompt, change all `%%` to `%`.